# Controller: Inheriting an route() Odoo 10

Tags: python, odoo, qweb

I want to inherit a route to insert other functions by calling another template. Because I work on two different modules. Here are my codes and results:
**Controller 1:**

```
@http.route(['/my/documents/add',
             '/my/documents/update/<int:document_id>'],
            type='http', auth='user', methods=['GET', 'POST'], website=True)
def add_document(self, redirect=None, document_type=None, document_id=None, modal_call=None, **kw):...............
```

**Controller 2:**

```
from odoo import http
from odoo.addons.partner_documents.controllers.main import WebsitePortalDocuments


class DocumentsCCPG(WebsitePortalDocuments):
    def getDocumentCCPG(self, **kw):
        response = super(DocumentsCCPG, self).getDocumentCCPG(**kw)
        return response
```

**Result with template :** 
[Result Web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSD8Y.png)

What is framed is my second template that inherits the first template. The problem is that I can not display my services (select tag). My controller is not well filled, I know but against I can not even access my second controller debeug (I use PyCharm). Someone would have any idea ?
thank you in advance

Comment: Thanks for edit. Can you help me ?

Comment: It's not very clear. You said you're trying to inherit a route, I guess it's the ``'/my/documents/add', '/my/documents/update/...'`` one. Then, don't you want to override the ``add_document`` function ? In this case you should do ``response = super(DocumentsCCPG, self).add_document(**kw)``. But I think you should show us more of your code.

Comment: Sorry, I'm french.
Yes, I want to modify this function add_document () (without deleting it) to add some fields of my second model. I will try your method.

Comment: No one to help me ?

Comment: Sorry it's still unclear to me... Can you please post the original